# SQL: join: find all objects that satisfy some requirements

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains a list of objects and which requirements they fulfill. Then I have a table that contains a list of tasks and which requirements an object must fulfill to be able to perform the task. I would like to query: given a task, show me all objects that can perform that task, and given an object, show me all tasks that object can perform:

Example:

task_req table

```
tasks   |    reqs
-----------------
taskA   |    req1
taskA   |    req2
taskA   |    req3
taskB   |    req4
taskB   |    req5
taskB   |    req6
```

So this table says that to perform taskA, requirements req1, req2, and req3 are needed.

obj_reqs table

```
object  |   reqs
----------------
obj1    |   req3
obj1    |   req4
obj2    |   req1
obj2    |   req2
obj2    |   req3
obj2    |   req4
```

So I could ask the question: which objects can perform taskA? The answer should be just one row:

```
tasks   |   objects
-------------------
taskA   |   object2
```

because obj2 is the only one that has fulfills requirements req1,req2,req3. Different question: which objects can perform taskB? The answer is none, because there's no object with requirements req4,req5,req6. The query should be handle logic where one task can be performed by multiple objects by returning multiple rows.

The question is: what query does this?

My problem is that I have managed to find such a query, but it seems to me too complicated. The query basically does: 
A) inner join task_reqs table with obj_reqs table, group by tasks and objs and count distinct requirements,
B) select tasks,count(distinct(reqs)) from task_reqs group by tasks,
C) inner join A and B on both task and count(distinct(reqs)).

Surely there's an easier way to do this query, right?

I'm pasting below the SQL code to generate the tables and my query.

```
create table task_reqs (task varchar, req varchar);
create table obj_reqs (object varchar, req varchar);
insert into task_reqs values ('taskA', 'req1');
insert into task_reqs values ('taskA', 'req2');
insert into task_reqs values ('taskA', 'req3');
insert into task_reqs values ('taskB', 'req4');
insert into task_reqs values ('taskB', 'req5');
insert into task_reqs values ('taskB', 'req6');
insert into obj_reqs values ('obj1','req1');
insert into obj_reqs values ('obj1','req3');
insert into obj_reqs values ('obj2','req1');
insert into obj_reqs values ('obj2','req2');
insert into obj_reqs values ('obj2','req3');
insert into obj_reqs values ('obj2','req4');
```

and my query:

```
select t.task,t.object,n.n_reqs
from (
    select task,object,count(distinct(obj_reqs.req)) as n_reqs
    from task_reqs
    inner join obj_reqs on task_reqs.req=obj_reqs.req
    group by task,object
) t
inner join (
    select task,count(distinct(req)) as n_reqs
    from task_reqs
    group by task
) n
on n.n_reqs=t.n_reqs and n.task=t.task;
```

which returns:

```
 task  | object | n_reqs 
-------+--------+--------
 taskA | obj2   |      3
```

Surely there's a simpler way.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. Enclosing a column used for `distinct` with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `count(distinct (a))` is the same as `count(distinct a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible simpler way:

```
select t.task, o.object, count(t.req) n_reqs
  from task_reqs t left join obj_reqs o on t.req = o.req
  group by t.task, o.object
  having o.object is not null and count(t.req) = (select count(req) from task_reqs where 
  task = t.task)
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/TEZMMJ55450)

Comment: This is my preferred solution. Would you add a SQL fiddle example, like the other responders did, please?

Comment: Sure. Now it is added.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a cross join of the tables:

```
select t.task, o.object, count(distinct t.req) n_reqs 
from task_reqs t cross join obj_reqs o
where t.task = 'taskA'
group by t.task, o.object
having count(distinct t.req) = count(case when t.req = o.req then 1 end)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a3PfVBqQZiCGksJwKwgfCn/1).
Results:

```
| task  | object | n_reqs |
| ----- | ------ | ------ |
| taskA | obj2   | 3      |
```

Comment: Isn't cross join really bad?

Comment: For 2 massive tables it is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems fine. I believe this is going to complicated no matter how you go after it since the join criteria and/or where predicates are going to be dependent on both `req` and the count of `req` matching.

Window functions *may* cut down on processing time here since you can eliminate a table scan from you original query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT task, object
FROM
  (
    SELECT task, 
      object, 
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY task, object) matchCount,
      trqs.reqCount
    FROM (SELECT task, req, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY task) as reqcount FROM task_reqs) trqs
      INNER JOIN obj_reqs orqs
        ON trqs.req = orqs.req
   ) taskreqcounter
WHERE matchCount = reqCount
```

If you have an index on `obj_reqs.req` I think you would find this query to be pretty quick too. If you are interested in only a particular task then you can add that to the `WHERE` clause in the inner most subquery (`trqs`).

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3a8d7c/1)

Reversing this logic works for question 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT task, object
FROM
  (
    SELECT task, 
      object, 
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY task, object) matchCount,
      orqs.reqCount
    FROM (SELECT object, req, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY object) as reqcount FROM obj_reqs) orqs
      INNER JOIN task_reqs trqs
        ON orqs.req = trqs.req
   ) taskreqcounter
WHERE matchCount = reqCount
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3a8d7c/3)